# Setting opening page in app-routing module doesn't redirect as expected

Tags: ionic-framework, routes

I have walkthrough page built using ion-slides.
I had set this page to be the first page to open when the app had launched in app-routing.module.ts:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'walkthrough',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

However if I change the starting page to any other page the app will consistently start with the waklthourgh page:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

All paths are set correctly:

```
{
    path: 'walkthrough',
    loadChildren: () => import('./walkthrough/walkthrough.module').then(m => m.WalkthroughPageModule)
  },

 {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
```

Any input appreciated.

EDIT: adding login routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LoginPageRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: What is inside the 'walkthrough' and 'login' routing-modules?

Comment: Do you mean the module.ts files?

Comment: I mean each routing.module.ts

Comment: Added the login routing.module.ts- the walkthrough does not have this file- it is imported form a sample project

Comment: Everything seems ok, and that should work properly! Could you provide more details?

Comment: Any particular details?

Comment: No, you can upload your project somewhere, and then I can take a look at it if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227861/discussion-between-dancingbush-and-arash-etemad).

Comment: Not sure what happened - try this https://github.com/dancingbush/Usermanual/tree/main/src